# Single SQL conditions in brackets

Tags: sql

I am refactoring some old oracle sql statements containing plenty of conditions. Some are single conditions put into brackets. Now, does the brackets matter for single conditions? Is there a difference between the two examples below?

example 1

```
WHERE
  (
         A = B
     AND B = C
  )
  AND ( A > 5 )
  AND ( B <> 0 )
```

example 2

```
WHERE
  (
         A = B
     AND B = C
  )
  AND A > 5
  AND B <> 0
```

Comment: none, actually you could even say WHERE A = B AND B = C AND A > 5 AND B <> 0. Be aware, though, when you use also other logic operators like OR..then you need brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about logic: you do need brackets if you have some OR logic, but in this case (only AND) it has no meaning. You can remove all brackets in your query.

And if we'll go deep: look the explain query analyze, you can see that interpreter puts brackets automatically even you missed it.

Comment: But even if you don't require logic you must NOT rely on your database to expect to apply the appropriate behavior.   It also certainly rears its ugly face when your training and they don't know how to appropriate logic.  and you get some wonky result set because of a lack of bracket-ing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there ain't any semantic differences.

In my experience usually this is either

- a relic of some old condition (maybe an `OR` was in that bracket somewhere in the past) or
- just the style of the dev working in this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two examples you have posted. Oracle query executes from the end i.e your where condition's last part is filtered first and runs back eg:- where first filter condition would be b<>0 then A>5 ,so on.

Its good practice to use brackets when using AND and OR operators together as without brackets soemtimes the logic is unclear ,otherwise with only AND operator bracket doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

All are same until you have only AND. But if you have any other operator then comes the question of [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators001.htm).

**example 1**

```
WHERE
  (
         A = B
     AND B = C
  )
  AND ( A > 5 )
  AND ( B <> 0 )
```

**example 2**

```
WHERE
  (
         A = B
     AND B = C
  )
  AND A > 5
  AND B <> 0
```

**example 3**

```
WHERE
      A = B
  AND B = C
  AND A > 5
  AND B <> 0
```